# Query to select last record which has same column value(date)

Tags: mysql, sql

table schema

```
id              date
----            -------
1020            1990-02-15
1020            1990-02-15
1060            1990-02-15
1020            1990-03-15
1020            1990-03-15
1020            1990-02-10
```

query to select last inserted record which has same date and where id = 1020
date format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: is there no AUTO Increment column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Since it's MySQL</strike>

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id=1020 
ORDER BY `date` desc 
LIMIT 1
```

but i still have a question for you, what if you have records like this?

```
1020            1/11/12
1020            1/12/12
1020            1/12/12
1020            1/13/12
```

what will it return?

In your case, the `date` is not currently formatted (*i guess it was saved as `VARCHAR`*) that is why you need to format it back to date using `STR_TO_DATE` function and from that display using your desired format.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%m/%d/%y'), '%d-%m-%Y') lastDate
FROM table 
WHERE id = 1020 
ORDER BY `date` desc 
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

So you need the record which has the same date right? Try this edit one. For this, it created a subquery which returns the latest date and has the same date.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 1020 AND
        `Date` = (
                    SELECT  MAX(`date`) maxDate
                    FROM    tableName
                    GROUP BY `date`
                    HAVING COUNT(`DATE`) > 1
                 )
```

Comment: @chetan what i mean is what date will it return from above example. what is datatype of column `date`?

Comment: datatype of date column is  date  . From above example  it will return 1020 1/12/12  only second because 1/13/12 is not valid if dd-mm-yyyy and my query is still not solved because i need both 2 and 3 row according to your example and i don't know number of  rows with same data , So i can't use limit

Comment: what is the use of HAVING COUNT(`DATE`) > 1 in above query . When I use above query as SELECT count(*)
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 1020 AND
        `Date` = (
                    SELECT  MAX(`date`) maxDate
                    FROM    tableName
                    GROUP BY `date`
                    HAVING COUNT(`DATE`) > 1
                 ) For one record it return 0 .

Comment: @chetan it will filter out number of records which has the same date, try to remove that and it will return the latest date (*with or without duplicate*)

Comment: how can i attain Count(*) motive .

Answer (score 2):

By last record I assume you mean the one with the most-current date....

```
select * from table where id=1020 order by date desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

```
select max(date) from table where id=1020;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SELECT * FROM schema WHERE id=1020 ORDERBY date DESC limit 1;
```

or choose max of the date you have like

```
SELECT MAX(date) from schema WHERE id = 1020;
```

Answer (score 0):

use max() and group your main column

```
select id, max(date) from tableName group by id;
```